# c# character shift/message decoder

Tags: c#, loops, character-encoding, streamreader

I am stuck on an extra credit class assignment.  It is:

Write a program that decodes secret messages read from a text file using an "alphabetic shift." 
You must:

1.) Read the encoded message from the attached MessageIn.txt file using StreamReader (see attached demo),
2.) Count the instance of each character in the file,
3.) The most common character in the message should be an "E". Use this information to calculate the amount of the shift,
4.) Print out the decoded message.

He will change the coded .txt message so we cant just find out the most used letter in the one given we have to write our code to find the most used character.

What I have now is:

```
namespace Assign_14
{
    class Program
    {
    private static StreamReader inFile;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            inFile = new StreamReader("MessageIN.txt");
            string s = inFile.ReadLine();

            int[] freq = new int[26];
            for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
            {
                string temp = s.Substring(i, 1);
                int itemp = (int)temp.ToCharArray()[0];

                freq[itemp - 65]++;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i + " " + freq[i]);
            }
        }
        catch (System.IO.IOException exc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR");
        }

    }
}
```

}
If anyone can help me on what to do next that would be great.  If someone finishes AND explains how they got it, I will buy them a steam game of their choice of $10 or less.

Comment: well I need figure it out so i can understand it for the final.  The book barely goes over the shift.

Answer (score 0):

While I don't really think it is appropriate for us to post answer code to do your homework for you, I will give you the pointer that if you consider capital and lower case letters, the freq array should be larger than 26.  You can also set a variable maxCount = 0, maxIndex = 0, and write a for loop to cycle through your freq array and find the maximum value.  If the value is larger than your current maxCount, set both maxCount and maxIndex.  At the end, the difference between the ASCII code of e and your maxIndex gives you your shift.

Comment: the array is for each letter of the alphabet. Also I emailed my teacher and it turns out it is extra credit because the book does not cover it fully.

Comment: Then you will need to call temp = temp.ToUpper(); in order to ensure that your offsets are not thrown off by lower case letters.  Also, you will need to skip a character if the character is not a letter.  You can test using Char.IsLetter(temp[0]).